# AppBar material ui fixed position not contained in grid

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

Hi all this is killing me. I cant figure it out. I changed my AppBar to position="fixed". What this causes is the appbar to not be contained within the container now it spans the entire screen. I cant figure it out any help please.

Answer (score 0):

Appbar
Container
Grid

did it this way and it worked was scared of getting keyboards thrown at me so thought harder thanks.